# Endless logging in

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a server and my friend is unable to login, but I am able to log in. His window freezes, and all he can do is click "cancel".

[image]
That's what I see in my console:

[image]
So... **What can we do to fix it?**

Comment: I have had this happen once, and the problem was that the computer that couldn't log in was mistakenly using a modded Minecraft version.  Installing Minecraft fresh in a brand new folder made it work.

Comment: This looks more like a connection problem. It appears your friend *Friedrich* is losing connection to your server right after connecting to it. Maybe try asking him to check his internet connection, and your own.

Answer (score -1):

It could be that you have not port-forwarded.

In this case, you can either:

- Download and install Hamachi, along with your friend, and use that to connect to each other (by creating a network in Hamachi, joining it together, and get your friend to connect using your Hamachi ipv4 address).

**OR**

- Port-forward your Minecraft (search on google/youtube for a tutorial on how to port-forward Minecraft), then ask your friend to connect using your public IP address.

The problem could also be that you were not giving him the correct IP address. Type in "ip" on google and you will be presented with your public IP address which you should give to your friend on Minecraft, providing you have already port-forwarded.

Comment: It has nothing to do whether he has port-forwarded or not. If he hasn't PF'd, his server wouldn't be printing out the fact he's losing connection.

Comment: @aytimothy It still might be resolved if he and his friend try Hamachi.

Comment: Hamachi may also be pointless as he has connection in the first place. (Just that it was unsustainable by the seems of it)

Comment: Possibly yes, but Hamachi may be worth a try if him and his friend are still experiencing the problem and have gone through standard procedures.